# Send Sms using ionic framework

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to send sms using ionic framework.I install this plugin:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin.git
```

In javascript:

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {

    var options = {
      replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
      android: {
        intent: '' // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
          //intent: '' // send SMS without open any other app
          //intent: 'INTENT' // send SMS inside a default SMS app
      }
    };

      $cordovaSms
        .send('+919915768727', 'This is some dummy text', options)
        .then(function() {
          alert('Success');
          // Success! SMS was sent
        }, function(error) {
          alert('Error');
          // An error occurred
        });

  });
```

Message is not send.this will alert error.I dont know where I am wrong.

```
cordova version:  5.2.0
Ionic version:  1.6.4
```

Comment: simple alert error which i was use in the code

Comment: Please log that error object , so that you can debug your problem. If you don't know how to see console.log from device, then use `ionic run android -l -c` , this will run application on your device and show logs in command window.

Comment: Or you can use this tool http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html , to monitor you logs.

Comment: (Monitor:8005): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

Comment: This is not error from plugin.Console your error with some prefix so you can filter it. Like this `console.log("YOUR-APP-NAME"+error);`

Comment: Have a look in github I uploaded a sample project how to use SMS by using Ionic Framework @KaranKumar

Answer (score -1):

you have place the function of $cordovaSMS in an $ionicPlatform function as

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
      $cordovaSms
      .send($scope.form.number, $scope.form.message, options)
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);

      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
    })
```

and I am uploading a demo project for you in  [git hub](https://github.com/anilkumar007/SMS) follow the steps in readme.md file of github 
Having any queries replay back

Comment: The example on gitHub that you have shared just opens the messaging app. Whereas the asker want to send sms directly via ionic rather than just opening an app and copying input text into message.

Comment: It is not possible to create an own SMS app in Ionic framework, because iPhone will not allow to use our SMS inbox folder for security reasons so I used an from where it will open the inbuilt SMS app. Read the development docs of iPhone before voting @Yatin

Comment: Its possible in android. Here you go https://github.com/cfjedimaster/Cordova-Examples/tree/master/contactpickerui

Comment: The plugin which you mentioned is to access the contacts from an android phone not an inbuilt SMS app, This is the plugin we  have to use  [link](https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin). Yeah For android I know how to access the SMS inbuilt but IOS is not possible

Comment: yes i gave the wrong plugin. but my point was that its possible in android.